# Does "buck" mean "disagree" or "challenge" in this sentence, and how formally?

Tags: meaning, formality

I heard this sentence from a show in TV, wants to know what does it mean.

> there are million free thinkers like us who refuse to obey the experts and buck their traditionalist fact.

by sentence structure, I guess it means disagree or challenge someone. If that's case, how formal is buck in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accoring to [OxfordDictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/buck) it means:

> Oppose or resist (something oppressive or inevitable)
>
> *‘the shares bucked the market trend’*

It is not very formal because it still carries the metaphor of a bucking horse.